# Is it possible to replace default signature in Hyperledger Fabric with schnorr signature?

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, digital-signature

I would like to know if Hyperledger Fabric does support use of custom signatures?

If so, can you point me to some documentation?

I tried to find out if it is possible to use schnorr signature in Hyperledger Fabric. I couldn't find anything useful in the documentation, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it is possible but it would require code changes to Fabric itself to support a different signature algorithm. For example, this code change implements ed25519 for Fabric:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/pull/3343

Some time ago, there was a proposal to rearchitect the crypto implementation in Fabric to make it more easily pluggable. I don't know of any work to actually make this happen.

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-rfcs/pull/34/files